# Ссылка this - неявный аргумент или явный первый параметр метода

Tags: java, методы

Встречаю следующие утверждения

- Ссылка `this` является неявным аргументом во всех методах экземпляра и делается на вызывающий объект.
- Начиная с `JDK 8` можно явным образом объявлять ссылку `this`  в качестве первого параметра метода.

Наверняка, общее в этих утверждениях только `this`, хотелось бы разобраться.
Для какой цели ссылка `this` является в одном случае неявным аргументом во всех методах экземпляра, а в другом случае, способной быть объявленной (с `JDK 8`) явным образом первым параметром метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что нам говорит по этому поводу [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1-220):

> Either way, the receiver parameter exists solely to allow the type of
>   the represented object to be denoted in source code, so that the type
>   may be annotated.

По-русски говоря, это даёт возможность `this` аннотировать.